# iOS- How do I make each cell in a table view bigger?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

This might be a noob question,but how do I make each cell in a UItableview bigger through interface builder?

Comment: There's not enough info to help you: please specify how you define table cells - statically, with a prototype cell, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the table view in your nib or storyboard.  Then show the Size Inspector.  (You can do this by choosing View > Utilities > Show Size Inspector… from the menu bar, among other ways.)  The first section of the Size Inspector is the Table View Size, and the first field in the Table View Size section is the Row Height.

[image: Row Height screen shot]

Changing the Row Height field in the nib has the same effect as setting the `rowHeight` property of the table view instance at runtime.

If you want rows to be different heights, you must either implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view's delegate, or use a storyboard with static cells.

Comment: Sorry for giving you a checkmark late, I am so mad because I did this and didnt work the first time, but for w/e reason it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set the `dataSource` and `delegate` to `self`, this should work:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForCellAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    return 50.0f; //Replace with how high you want. 
}
```

<sub>Typed on mobile, test before shipping.</sub>

Yes, it's code, but it's a whole lot easier than anything else. Easier to change, too.

Comment: The OP wanted it to be done in IB not via code even if it is easier.

Comment: @max So? I'm not expecting rep. I'm just giving options.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Table View Cell, then choose the ruler icon on the right panel, check Custom next to Row Hight, then just change the row height.

To change the width select the view controller, find Simulated Metrics in the tab to the left of the ruler, change Size to Freeform, then select the Table View, go back to the ruler tab and you should be able to change the width which the cell will adjust to if Autoresize Subviews is checked (which it is by default).